# Set animation to linearLayout background image

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I set animation to linearLayout background image .
I can reach LinearLayout by id but I dont want to animate it because it has some views I dont want to animate them, so I want to animate the background only .

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mohamed71.guest_service.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
   android:background="@drawable/welcome">

......
......


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some id for your LinearLayout, then animate your layout.

**EDITED:**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(your_layout_id);
// Drawable drawable = linearLayout.getBackground();
// do animation on drawable
linearLayout.setAnimation(YourAnimation);
```

**EDITED 2**

Try use background with this code inside your layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Then you can animate **android:id="@+id/iv_background"**

Comment: I will reach the Layout by its id , then I need to set animation to its background img .

Comment: LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(xxx);
    Drawable drawable = linearLayout.getBackground();
    // do animation on drawable

linearLayout.setAnimation(YourAnimation);

Comment: It didn't work , the animation is set on all views in the Layout , I want to set the animation on the background only .

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id to the linearLayout in `XML` then you can reach it by `findViewById`.**Please note your goal is to animate the `LinearLayout` not the `image`.

If you use `XML` :

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/your_id">
  </LinearLayout>
```

When you set its id, you can reach the layout.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(xxx);
    Drawable drawable = linearLayout.getBackground();
    // do animation on drawable
```

Comment: I dont want to set animation for Layout.I just want to animate its background   imag , so I need to reach the layout by its id then animate its background

Comment: Can you reach the Layout?

Comment: I will reach the Layout by its id , then I need to set animation to its background img .

Comment: What kind of animation?

Comment: scale animation .

Comment: I can not come out why not do animation on Layout? Is there any difficulty?

Comment: the Layout has some views I dont want to animate them , I want to animate the background only

Comment: Then I think you can use a View whose width and height is `Match_Parent` so you can animate this view.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)'

Comment: Do you use `View#startAnimation` ?